# Word for "things which exist"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a noun that denotes "things which exist"?  The only noun form of existence that I can find/think of is "existence" which is the condition of existing, not the things which do.

It's to summarize the tools for a given task that already exist, in a presentation outline (so it needs to be a single word, but I can't give an example sentence!).  The other headings are RCA/Techniques/Lacunae.

ETA: Beings implies a certain amount of animacy, which these things definitely don't have.

Comment: Needs more context. How are you planning to use this word? Can you give us a sample sentence?

Comment: Being:  something that exists or is thought to exist.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Being

Comment: @Josh61: My chocolate bar is a *being*?

Comment: @ermanen - My chocolate bar is an  existent? :))

Comment: @Josh61: Yes it is. But existent is usually used as an adjective.

Comment: If you don't have another heading that refers to tools that don't already exist, then why can't you just use *Tools*?

Comment: That might work @pacoverflow, but the whole topic is about a tool in the making, so a heading Tools seems a little confusing to me.

Comment: The thing I would be interested to know is what forms the antonym of something which 'exists', given that 'space', 'a thought', 'a contradiction' and 'emptiness' all 'exist'.

Comment: Present, available, real, prepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for a **noun**, not an adjective (e.g. extant) or something like "ontology", I suggest either "**ens**" or "**entity**".

- "**[Ens](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ens)**" is the noun derived from the Latin verb "esse" (to be); its plural form is "entia".
- "**Entity**" is derived from "entitas" in Medieval Latin, and ultimately from "ens". See also [Wikipedia's definition of entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity) as "something that exists as itself, as a subject or as an object, actually or potentially, concretely or abstractly, physically or not".

Answer (score 6):

The adjective *extant* may be relevant, and suitable for a column heading by itself.  From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extant#Adjective), it means “Still in existence” or  “Currently existing; not having disappeared”, etc.

The word *[entities](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entities)* also is relevant. From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entity#English), *entity* means “That which has a distinct existence as an individual unit” or  “An existent something that has the properties of being real, and having a real existence”.

You might also consider terms like *stocked*, *items*, *things*, *on hand*, *tools*.

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend referring to the things you take to exist as an *ontology*. Within philosophy, "ontology" was originally used to mean "the study of what things exist", but it's now common for it to be used (as a singular noun) to mean "the things which exist". For example:

> As for Lewis's own views, with respect to the second question they are fairly unambiguous: He is quite clear that a proper ontology must include not just particulars but also properties and relations...

Source: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lewis-metaphysics/

Somewhat similarly (though I know less about this), information scientists apparently use "an ontology" to mean "the things which my computer system takes to exist" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)).

So in your case, I would have thought that "Ontology" would be an appropriate heading: you are outlining an ontology of tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing technical documents, you could use this structure:

> The XYZ feature is present in the application.

The phase *is present* is common in tech docs, i.e. it exists in the software.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, "existing tools" sounds reasonable to me. Not sure there is a single word to represent the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

*Existent* is a noun for things that exists.

> *n.* One that exists.
>
> *http://www.thefreedictionary.com/existent*

Though, noun form can be considered archaic in everyday speech and the noun form is usually used in philosophical contexts. *Existent* is usually used as an adjective.

You can consider *subsistence* also.

> *n.* Something that has real or substantial existence.
>
> *http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subsistence*

**Note:** This answer is context-free.